# Security vulnerablility issue in ios mobile app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

Security vulnerability issue in ios mobile app.
Below is the result from https://www.immuniweb.com/mobile:
Predictable Random Number Generator CWE-338

Details:

> File: ios/Payload/ios.app/FridaGadget.dylib Binary match usage of
>   'random' function/method. Binary match usage of 'srand'
>   function/method. File: ios/Payload/ios.app/ios Binary match usage of
>   'random' function/method. File:
>   ios/Payload/ios.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib Binary match usage
>   of 'random' function/method. File:
>   ios/Payload/ios.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib Binary match
>   usage of 'random' function/method. File:
>   ios/SwiftSupport/iphoneos/libswiftCore.dylib Binary match usage of
>   'random' function/method. File:
>   ios/SwiftSupport/iphoneos/libswiftFoundation.dylib Binary match usage
>   of 'random' function/method.

How to overcome this?
please help on this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an overzealous security scan. It found that some libraries are using the C function `random` for some of their internal uses but since this usage is in libswiftCore and various other libraries and we do not know how those functions are actually used, it is both impossible to fix and impossible to know if it is really problematic.

Using an "insecure random" function for generating a random color on the screen for display, would not be a security issue.  We do not need a cryptographically secure random number generator for this task, even if it can be predicted it wouldn't be a problem.

So it all depends on the usage of the app, and how each of those libraries are going to be using that random function.  I would silence that warning if your app is written in Swift.